# Windows XP how to install complex script and right-to-left language files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, globalization

In windows XP I want to install complex script and right-to-left language files. I want to do it programatically while installing my localized application. Currently I have to give instructions to user to follow steps which doesnt look nice.

1. Open Regional and Language Options in Control Panel.
2. On the Languages tab, under Supplemental language support, select the Install files for complex script and right-to-left languages check box.
3. Click OK or Apply.
4. After the files are installed, you must restart your computer.

I want to do all this programatically while installing application. If it ask for XP's CD its ok. IF there any way I can provide required files would be great.